# Trying to find a elegant way of finding adjacent element in a 2d array in a multi-direction

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I want to find the neighboring element that surrounds `p`. the program below doesn't print of the neighbors

I know we can use brute-force approach, like this:

```
array[i-1][i]
array[i-1][i-1]
array[i][i-1]
array[i+1][i]
```

and so on...
But, I worry that it would get tedious to check every possible places of that element `p`. I am trying to figure out an elegant way to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void draw_board();
int row_number, column_number;
char mark_board(char mark, int row_num, int column_num);
char find_neighborhood(char board[6][6], int i, int j);

char board[6][6] = {
    { '0','0','0','0','0','0' },
    { '0','1','2','3','0','0' },
    { '0','4','P','5','0','0' },
    { '0','6','7','8','0','0' },
    { '0','0','0','0','0','0' },
    { '0','0','0','0','0','0' }
};

int main() {
    draw_board();

    find_neighborhood(board[6][6], 3, 3); // trying to find neighbor of char p 
    
    return 0;
}

void draw_board() {
    printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
    printf("   -----------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // rows
        printf("%i| ", i + 1);// row number to be printed
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { // columns
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

char find_neighborhood(char board[6][6], int row_num, int col_num) {
    int rows = sizeof(board); // row limit 
    int columns = sizeof(board[0]) - 1; // column limit
  
    for (int j = row_num - 1; j <= row_num + 1; j++) {
        for (int i = col_num - 1; i <= col_num + 1; i++) {
            if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < columns && j < rows && !(j == row_num && i == col_num)) {
                printf("The neighbor of p is: %c\n", board[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing bad about tedious. Programming isn't literature. Just loop rows and loop columns and protect edges. Sometimes brute-force isn't the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the good points made by @chqlie, you have other areas that pose significant *"anti-patters"* or just plain *"code-smells"*. The most vexing is your mixing of 1-based rows and columns with 0-based array indexing. In C, all indexing is 0-based. When you write functions manipulating arrays, all indexing should be 0-based. Not only does this make your code easier to follow and maintain, it removes the risk of an *off-by-one* error associated with mixing 1-based and 0-based indexing.

If you must take 1-based coordinates from the user, then map 1-based indexing to 0-based indexing before you call your array manipulation function. If you don't do it at the point of input, then make it clear to anyone maintaining your code that an indexing changes is occurring. A simple commented function will do, e.g.

```
/* convert 1-based rows/cols to 0-based indexes */
int toindex (int rc)
{
    return rc ? rc - 1 : rc;
}
```

and call:

```
    /* DANGER mixing 1-based & 0-based indexes !!! */
    find_neighborhood (board, toindex (3), toindex (3));
```

Don't use *MagicNumbers* in your code. (e.g. `6`). This limits your code to a single arrays size requiring picking though all loop and array declarations and recompiling your code just to handle a change of array size. Instead:

```
#define ROWS 6          /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS

void draw_board (const char board[ROWS][COLS]);
void find_neighborhood (const char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col);
```

This impacts how you write you reading in `draw_board()` as well, e.g.

```
void draw_board(const char board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    fputs ("  ", stdout);               /* don't use MagicNumbers */
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)      /* create your headings   */
        printf ("%2d", i + 1);          /* from defined constants */
    fputs ("\n   ", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * COLS - 1; i++)
        putchar ('-');
    putchar ('\n');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf (" %d|", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf (j ? " %c" : "%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    } 
}
```

You have another subtle issue with your declaration of board as `char board[6][6]` and then your use of the `const` qualifier in your function parameter lists. Pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C. [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.1 Pointer declarators(p2)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1p2). This is the result of array/pointer conversion on a 2D array resulting in a *pointer-to-array* of actual type `char (*)[6]`. Try it, enable full warnings with  `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (or `/W3` on VS)

As for a "more-elegant" ways to write `find_neighborhood()` your though of nested loops and bounds checks at the edges is as good as any other approach. You started out in that direction, and other than writing a set of `if...else if...else if...else` conditionals, it probably a good choice. Eliminating your 1-based/0-based problem it could be written as:

```
/* all array manipulation functions should use 0-based indexes */
void find_neighborhood (const char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col)
{
    printf ("\nThe neighbors of '%c' are:\n\n", board[row][col]);
    
    for (int i = row ? row - 1 : row; i <= (row < ROWS - 1 ? row + 1 : row); i++) {
        for (int j = col ? col - 1 : col; j <= (col < COLS - 1 ? col + 1 : col); j++) {
            if (i == row && j == col)
                fputs ("  ", stdout);
            else
                printf (" %c", board[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 6          /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS

void draw_board (const char board[ROWS][COLS]);
void find_neighborhood (const char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col);

/* convert 1-based rows/cols to 0-based indexes */
int toindex (int rc)
{
    return rc ? rc - 1 : rc;
}


int main() {
    
    const char board[ROWS][COLS] = {    /* avoid global variables   */
        { '0','0','0','0','0','0' },
        { '0','1','2','3','0','0' },    /* pointers to arrays with  */
        { '0','4','P','5','0','0' },    /* different qualifiers are */
        { '0','6','7','8','0','0' },    /* incompatible in ISO C    */
        { '0','0','0','0','0','0' },
        { '0','0','0','0','0','0' },
    };
    draw_board(board);
    
    /* DANGER mixing 1-based & 0-based indexes !!! */
    find_neighborhood (board, toindex (3), toindex (3));
}

void draw_board(const char board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    fputs ("  ", stdout);               /* don't use MagicNumbers */
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)      /* create your headings   */
        printf ("%2d", i + 1);          /* from defined constants */
    fputs ("\n   ", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * COLS - 1; i++)
        putchar ('-');
    putchar ('\n');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf (" %d|", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf (j ? " %c" : "%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    } 
}

/* all array manipulation functions should use 0-based indexes */
void find_neighborhood (const char board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col)
{
    printf ("\nThe neighbors of '%c' are:\n\n", board[row][col]);
    
    for (int i = row ? row - 1 : row; i <= (row < ROWS - 1 ? row + 1 : row); i++) {
        for (int j = col ? col - 1 : col; j <= (col < COLS - 1 ? col + 1 : col); j++) {
            if (i == row && j == col)
                fputs ("  ", stdout);
            else
                printf (" %c", board[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/board_neighbors
   1 2 3 4 5 6
   -----------
 0|0 0 0 0 0 0
 1|0 1 2 3 0 0
 2|0 4 P 5 0 0
 3|0 6 7 8 0 0
 4|0 0 0 0 0 0
 5|0 0 0 0 0 0

The neighbors of 'P' are:

 1 2 3
 4   5
 6 7 8
```

When you look for a "more elegant" way of doing anything, in the end you will get a fair amount of opinion built in. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: that quite a good way of implementing it that I am quite new to the C language, i am bound to have newbie mistakes and code-smells.

Comment: How would enable a full warning in visual studio code? is it the same as in Visual Studio community?

Comment: It depends on what compiler you are using with visual studio code. If you are using the normal VS compile (`cl.exe`), the `/W3` will enable essentially all usable warnings (`/W4` provides additional non-code warnings). If gcc/clang, then `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (and consider `-Wshadow` to catch shadowed variables). For all other compilers, you just have to check the man page or help to see what they use for options. All compilers will have similar flags that allow you to enable warnings.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- `find_neighborhood(board[6][6], 3, 3);` is incorrect: you should write this instead:

  ```
    find_neighborhood(board, 3, 3);
  ```
- in `find_neighborhood`, the definition `int rows = sizeof(board);` initializes `rows` to the size of a pointer, not the number of rows in the matrix. You should use explicit constants or pass the dimensions as extra arguments.
- `find_neighborhood()` performs many tests... But that's the core of the question.
- `row_number`, `column_number` and `board` should not be global variables. It is confusing that some functions use the global variables and others take them as arguments (with the same name).

Here is a modified version:

```
void find_neighborhood(char board[6][6], int row, int col) {
    for (int j = max(0, row - 1); j <= min(row + 1, 6); j++) {
        for (int i = max(0, col - 1); i <= min(col + 1, 6); i++) {
            if (j != row || i != col) {
                printf("The neighbor of p is: %c\n", board[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is an elegant way to address your objective: you can define `board` as an 8x8 array where the first and last rows and columns are always empty. The *active* part of the board has index values in the range `1..6`.

Here is a modified version with this approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void draw_board(const char board[8][8]);
char mark_board(char board[8][8], char mark, int row, int col);
void find_neighborhood(char board[8][8], int row, int col);

int main() {
    int row_number, column_number;
    char board[8][8] = {
        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
        { 0, '0','0','0','0','0','0', 0 },
        { 0, '0','1','2','3','0','0', 0 },
        { 0, '0','4','P','5','0','0', 0 },
        { 0, '0','6','7','8','0','0', 0 },
        { 0, '0','0','0','0','0','0', 0 },
        { 0, '0','0','0','0','0','0', 0 },
        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    };
    draw_board(board);

    find_neighborhood(board, 4, 4); // trying to find neighbors of char p 
    
    return 0;
}

void draw_board(const char board[8][8]) {
    printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
    printf("   -----------\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { // rows
        printf("%i| ", i);  // row number to be printed
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) { // columns
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

void find_neighborhood(char board[8][8], int row, int col) {
    char save = board[row][col];
    board[row][col] = 0;
    for (int j = row - 1; j <= row + 1; j++) {
        for (int i = col - 1; i <= col + 1; i++) {
            if (board[j][i] != 0) {
                printf("The neighbor of p is: %c\n", board[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    board[row][col] = save;
}
```